# header location encodes link for second time

Tags: php, redirect, header, urlencode

i'm having problem with encode.

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [pg_salt] => 52f1ef56308ae
    [pg_merchant_id] => 82
    [pg_order_id] => 22
    [pg_lifetime] => 86400
    [pg_amount] => 501.00
    [pg_description] => order number #22
    [pg_user_phone] => 79213123763072
    [pg_user_contact_email] => t.muradyan@test.ru
    [pg_user_mail] => t.muradyan@test.ru
    [pg_site_url] => http://bitrix.local
    [pg_check_url] => http://bitrix.local/n/check.php
    [pg_result_url] => http://bitrix.local/n/result.php
    [pg_request_method] => POST
    [pg_success_url] => http://bitrix.local/n/success.php
    [pg_refund_url] => http://bitrix.local/n/refund.php
    [pg_success_url_method] => AUTOPOST
    [pg_failure_url] => http://bitrix.local/n/failure.php
    [pg_failure_url_method] => POST
    [pg_sig] => 6bd3ff87a38a123876841e4312d6f9cb
)
```

Then i'm converting it to query string via:

```
$strQuery = http_build_query($arrRequest)
```

$strQuery value

```
pg_salt=52f1ef56308ae&pg_merchant_id=82&pg_order_id=22&pg_lifetime=86400&pg_amount=501.00&pg_description=order+number+%2322&pg_user_phone=79163763072&pg_user_contact_email=t.muradyan%40platron.ru&pg_user_mail=t.muradyan%40platron.ru&pg_site_url=http%3A%2F%2Fbitrix.local&pg_check_url=http%3A%2F%2Fbitrix.local%2Fplatron%2Fcheck.php&pg_result_url=http%3A%2F%2Fbitrix.local%2Fplatron%2Fresult.php&pg_request_method=POST&pg_success_url=http%3A%2F%2Fbitrix.local%2Fplatron%2Fsuccess.php&pg_refund_url=http%3A%2F%2Fbitrix.local%2Fplatron%2Frefund.php&pg_success_url_method=AUTOPOST&pg_failure_url=http%3A%2F%2Fbitrix.local%2Fplatron%2Ffailure.php&pg_failure_url_method=POST&pg_sig=6bd3ff87a38a123876841e4312d6f9cb
```

Then i'm redirecting via header location:

```
header('location: http://test.ru/test.php?'.$strQuery)
```

And getting error (error doesnt matter), because of twice encoding. When i enter into that link, my query string is:

```
pg_salt=52f1ef56308ae&pg_merchant_id=82&pg_order_id=22&pg_lifetime=86400&pg_amount=501.00&pg_description=order+number+%252322&pg_user_phone=1112&pg_user_contact_email=test%2540test.ru&pg_user_mail=test%2540test.ru&pg_site_url=http%253A%252F%252Fbitrix.local&pg_check_url=http%253A%252F%252Fbitrix.local%252Fn%252Fcheck.php&pg_result_url=http%253A%252F%252Fbitrix.local%252Fn%252Fresult.php&pg_request_method=POST&pg_success_url=http%253A%252F%252Fbitrix.local%252Fplatron%252Fsuccess.php&pg_refund_url=http%253A%252F%252Fbitrix.local%252Fn%252Frefund.php&pg_success_url_method=AUTOPOST&pg_failure_url=http%253A%252F%252Fbitrix.local%252Fn%252Ffailure.php&pg_failure_url_method=POST&pg_sig=6bd3ff87a38a123876841e4312d6f9cb
```

As you can see it encodes twice, for example:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fbitrix.local
```

And

```
http%253A%252F%252Fbitrix.local
```

I'm not using urlencode function anywhere, why it is encoding for second time, i dont know. I meeting this problem for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

see : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

and look :

> If enc_type is PHP_QUERY_RFC1738, then encoding is performed per » RFC 1738 and the
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type, which implies that
> spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs. If enc_type is
> PHP_QUERY_RFC3986, then encoding is performed according to » RFC 3986,
> and spaces will be percent encoded (%20).